# Multiply all elements in each row of an array by numbers in a 1D array

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a torch tensor (x) of shape [16,3,32,32], 16 images, 3 colour channels 32x32. I'm doing diffusion and need to apply the following formula to the images

`return sqrt_alpha_hat * x + sqrt_one_minus_alpha_hat * error`

Error has the same dimensions as x. This works fine when sqrt_alpha_hat and sqrt_one_minus_alpha_hat are integers, the tensors are all multiplied by the number and then added up. I want to multiply each image by a different value. So my sqrt_alpha_hat and sqrt_one_minus_alpha_hat are 1D arrays of size 32, one number for each image. Keep in mind this array is in CUDA so some np functions won't work.

I tried using np.fill to create a massive array with format:

[[[1 ... 1], ... [1 ... 1] (32 columns)
...                        (32 rows)
[1 ... 1], ... [1 ... 1]],

...                        (3 colour channels)

[[1 ... 1], ... [1 ... 1]
...
[1 ... 1], ... [1 ... 1]]]

...                       (16 images)

[[[16 ... 16], ... [16 ... 16]
...
[16 ... 16], ... [16 ... 16]],

...

[[16 ... 16], ... [16 ... 16]
...
[16 ... 16], ... [16 ... 16]]]

but that didn't work. There surely must be a simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Used

```
sqrt_alpha_hat_table = torch.stack([torch.full(x.shape[1:], sqrt_alpha_hat[i]) for i in range(x.shape[0])]).to(device)
```

Answer (score 0):

The "correct" way to do this (vectorized rather than loop-based, and without allocating lots of memory for repeating row vectors) is with `expand()`. I'll assume that you meant either that `sqrt_alpha_hat` is of size [16], or that there are 32 images, or that you made a semantic error somewhere else in your description.

```
# transform from size [n_images] to size [n_images,1,1,1]
sqrt_alpha_hat = sqrt_alpha_hat.unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(1)

# broadcast (view tensor view, rather than copying values) across new 
dimensions to size [n_images,3,32,32] 
sqrt_alpha_hat = sqrt_alpha_hat.expand(n_images,3,32,32)

# same for sqrt_one_minus_alpha_hat
... 

# now you can multiply and add easily because the dimensions of all arrays match
return sqrt_alpha_hat * x + sqrt_one_minus_alpha_hat * error
```

As a general rule, probably best to stick to torch functions rather than np functions when using pytorch tensors to avoid issues such as CUDA incompatibility etc.